# React Native Azure Auth logout without redirecting to webpage

Tags: android, react-native, azure-active-directory

I have an react native app that uses azure ad for sign in process.Currently i use  [react-native-azure-auth](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth) to make this happen but the problem i'm facing is when i tried to logout it redirects to a webpage asking the user to sign out from the browser as well making the sign out process an extra step can we avoid this i tried checking the library for any config but no sucess can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

I have workaround for it, just clear your local cache where you storing data and make user logout.

now when user login use this

```
azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({ scope: 'openid', prompt: 'login' });
```

so it will ask new login.